# Change src of element loaded with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm trying to alter the `src` of `img`s loaded via. AJAX, wherein the `<select>` and `<option>` elements used to control the function are also loaded by AJAX.

I'm trying to do this in order to change the size of Flickr images on the page.

I've tried loading the element, and calling an existing function to update it, but of course the `<select>` option doesn't exist on document.ready() and thus returns null when I try to get it.

I've also tried loading a new `<script type='text/javascript'></script>` in the PHP file I'm using for my XML response, but although this shows on the page it obviously isn't picked up as a source.

How can I tell the Document to 're-ready' itself, or acknowledge new sources?

Here's my code as it stands:

*Making the request*

```
    function makeRequest (url, userID, searchString, selectedLicense) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("userID", userID);
        formData.append("searchString", searchString);
        formData.append("selectedLicense", selectedLicense);

        var xmlRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlRequest.open("POST", url, true);
            xmlRequest.send(formData);

        xmlRequest.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlRequest.readyState===4 && xmlRequest.status===200) {
                document.getElementById("working...").innerHTML="<p style='background-color:#BCED91; width:200px; text-align:center;'>Done!</p>";
                document.getElementById("results").innerHTML=xmlRequest.responseText;
            } else {
                document.getElementById("results").innerHTML="<p>Ready State: " + xmlRequest.readyState + "</p> <p>Status Code: " + xmlRequest.status + "</p>";
            }
        }
    }
```

*The PHP*

```
//more code before
        $resultString = $resultString . "<script type='text/javascript'>"
                                        . "function sizeChanged(i, select) {
                                                var sel = getSelectedOptionValue(select);
                                                var imgURL = document.getElementById(i.toString());

                                                alert(imgURL);
                                            }"
                                      . "</script>";

        //main loop
        foreach ($XML->photos->photo as $photo):
            $resultString = $resultString . '<div class="photoBox"' . photoBox($photoCounter) . "> <p>" . $photoCounter . ". <a href=\"" . $baseURL . $photo['owner'] . "/" . $photo['id'] . "\">" . $photo['title'] . "</a>" . "</p>"
                                          . " <p>" . "<img id='" . $photoCounter . "' src=\"http://farm" . $photo['farm'] . $imgURL . "/" . $photo['server'] . "/" . $photo['id'] . "_" . $photo['secret'] . "_" . $size . "\" alt=\"" . $photo['title'] . "\">" . "</p>"
                                          . "<select form='addInformationForm' id='selectSize" . $photoCounter . "' onChange='return sizeChanged(" . $photoCounter . ", selectSize" . $photoCounter . ");'>"
                                            . "<option value='n'>Small (320)</option>"
                                            . "<option value='z' selected='selected'>Medium (640)</option>"
                                            . "<option value='h'>Large (1600)</option>"
                                          . "</select>"
                                          . "</div>";
            $photoCounter++;
        endforeach;
//more code here
echo $resultString;
```

*The HTML Output (Example)*

```
<div class="photoBox" style="background-color:#FFFFFF">
    <p>1. <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/25053835@N03/8427833074">Killip's Adirondack Travelog, page 20</a></p>
    <p><img id="1" src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com//8184/8427833074_2f7e22e7ce_z.jpg" alt="Killip's Adirondack Travelog, page 20"></p>
    <select form="addInformationForm" id="selectSize1" onChange="return sizeChanged(1, selectSize1);">
         <option value="n">Small (320)</option>
         <option value="z" selected="selected">Medium (640)</option>
         <option value="h">Large (1600)</option></select>
</div>
```

Any advice much appreciated!

NOTE: This code is for an internal tool, not a client-facing website.

Comment: If you were using jQuery you could use _event delegation_ to solve this problem.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning _event delegation_, I have Googled it and found many vanilla JavaScript tutorials for event delegation, maybe they will be some help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<select>` doesn't exists at `onload`, but it does when you create it:

```
var res = document.getElementById("results");
xmlRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlRequest.readyState===4 && xmlRequest.status===200) {
        document.getElementById("working...").innerHTML="<p style='background-color:#BCED91; width:200px; text-align:center;'>Done!</p>";
        res.innerHTML = xmlRequest.responseText;
        var select = res.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
        /* Use select here */
    } else {
        res.innerHTML="<p>Ready State: " + xmlRequest.readyState + "</p> <p>Status Code: " + xmlRequest.status + "</p>";
    }
};
```

Note that the `<img>` element should be available too, but you won't know its dimensions because it won't be downloaded. If you want to wait until it's loaded, you can add a `load` event listener.

Comment: Cheers :) I can actually tell the img's dimensions because the src contains, for instance, an `n`, `z`, `m`, `l`, etc. based on what dimensions it is, so I load the images based on that information. Thanks for the response, it's really helpful.

Comment: Hi, although your answer is partially helpful and I wanted to believe it would be this simple, it doesn't seem like it quite solves my problem, so I've had to unaccept. I need to call a function to change the img element from the select element, but either the select element doesn't know that the sizeChanged() function exists (this happens if I define the function where you suggest I define it), or the sizeChanged() function doesn't know that the img element exists (if I define the function outside this area). I can't think of a way around this.

Comment: Never mind, I worked it out! I defined the function as `var sizeChanged = function(){};` and then simply changed what the var referred to on receipt of response.